# Codility - Stone Wall - Stack and Queue

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, queue

It is about a lesson in Codility, 
after several times reading, still I could not understand.

Link: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/stone_wall/

The part that I don't understand:

> H[I] is the height of the wall from I to I+1 meters to the right of its left end. In particular, H[0] is the height of the wall's left end and H[N−1] is the height of the wall's right end.

Comment: watch this if anyone still needs to understand that!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhBJ7MqjF-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each wall is of fixed width, so when it say "H[I] is the height of the wall from I to I+1 meters" it means H[I] is height of wall H[I] until start of next wall H[I+1].

H[0] is the left most wall and H[N-1] is right most wall.